# parseFloat with IF statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get *IF* statements working inside a variable...

Look at the text under *//paypal variables*...when I start with **price: if(item.quantity="4")**

```
 product.find('.product-buy').click(function(e) {
                    //check if option is set
                    var option = $(this).attr('option') || '';
                    var item = {
                        group: product.parent().attr('id'),
                        id: product.attr('id'),
                        option: option || 'NA',
        LOOK HERE---->>>   quantity: parseInt(product.attr('minimum'+option),10) || 1,
                        minimum: parseInt(product.attr('minimum'+option),10) || 1,
                        //TEST
                         gap: parseFloat(product.attr('gap'+option)),
                        //TEST

                        //paypal variables
                        name: product.attr('name'+option),

    AND HERE---->>>   price: if(item.quantity="4")
                        {
                            parseFloat(product.attr('price'+option))
                            }
                            if(item.quantity="8")
                        {
                            parseFloat(product.attr('price2'+option))
                            }
                            if(item.quantity="12")
                        {
                            parseFloat(product.attr('price3'+option))
                            }

                        shipping: product.attr('shipping'+option),
                        number: product.attr('number'+option),
                        handling: product.attr('handling'+option)
                    };
                    addToCart(item,true);
                    e.preventDefault();
                }).fadeTo(0, 0.7).hover(hoverHandler(300, 1), hoverHandler(300, settings.buttonsOpacity));
              //set currency sign 
              if (settings.currencySign) {
                product.find('.product-currency').html(settings.currencySign);
              }
        });
```

So basicly, I want the item.price value to parseFloat the '**price**' attribute if the **quantity** attribute is equal to 4...to parseFloat the '**price2**' attribute if the **quantity** is equal to 8...and parseFloat the '**price3**' attribute if the **quantity** is equal to 12.

As you can see, for now I tried :

```
                    price: if(item.quantity="4")
                    {
                        parseFloat(product.attr('price'+option))
                        }
                        if(item.quantity="8")
                    {
                        parseFloat(product.attr('price2'+option))
                        }
                        if(item.quantity="12")
                    {
                        parseFloat(product.attr('price3'+option))
                        }
```

But it's not working. Any ideas?

thank you!

Comment: Is it just me, or are all of your comparisons actually assignments?

Comment: `=` -> assignment, `==` and `===` -> comparison

Answer (score 1):

You can't embed an if-statement inside an expression like this in Javascript. The language does not allow it.

Assign the value to a variable, and then assign the `price` attribute of the object you are creating to that variable.

```
var price = 0;
if(item.quantity==="4") {
    price = parseFloat(product.attr('price'+option))
}
else if ... {
} 
...

var item = {..., price: price, ...}
```

Comment: But, `item.quantity` would still not exist. You'd need to calculate that one beforehand as well.

Comment: You can also use a self-executing anonymous function, and have it return the result.

Comment: Yes, I copied the if statement code without actually reading it. The point is the same. You cannot a) assign variables to the result of an if block, b) refer to attributes of an object in the same statement defining the object.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the other comment, that's right but you can also put everything in a self-executing anonymous function that returns the price value:

```
price: (function(){
  var price;
  ...
  return price;
}())
```

Comment: At the time the function is executed, `item.quantity` would still not exist (which is required to calculate `price`).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the ternary operator.

```
price: item.quantity == "4" ? parseFloat(product.attr('price'+option)) : (
    item.quantity == "8" ? parseFloat(product.attr('price2'+option)) : (
        item.quantity == "12" ? parseFloat(product.attr('price3'+option))
    )
),
```

(Though this doesn't account for the fact that `item.quantity` would be undefined at that point, as pointed out in the comments on matt b's answer. Simply defining a `quantity` variable outside the `item` object at first would probably be a simple fix.)

Comment: Isn't the quantity variable defined few lines before? --> quantity: parseInt(product.attr('minimum'+option),10) || 1,

Comment: @user1388136 See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823791/parsefloat-with-if-statement/10823879#comment14089508_10823822

Comment: So I would have to make the quantity variable Global? I'm not sure that I understand